# Need to fetch matching records with provided job name in the list present in one of the column of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Df=[id,name,list[job_nm]]
Need to find all the rows whose matching job name is present in the list.
Using pandas dataframe.. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi Naman! Thanks for your question. There's a few problems with it that make it difficult to answer: 1. there's no data, 2. it's likely to be flagged as a duplicate, as there are many many other similar questions on here (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811188/filtering-pandas-dataframe-in-python). I would look at other similar answered questions, and then if you are sure your question is asking something different, add some sample data to your question so there can be a better understanding of what specifically you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering pandas dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811188/filtering-pandas-dataframe-in-python)